# SQL Server SMO on IIS with Windows Auth

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, smo, windows-authentication

I'm getting a strange error when I enable windows authentication on IIS and try to run some database update scripts:

> Invalid token for impersonation - it
>   cannot be duplicated.

I have not enabled any explicit impersonation.

I have narrowed it down to being something to do with SMO as when I change to a normal `SqlClient` and use `ExecuteNonQuery`, the problem goes away. This unfortunately is not a long term solution as the update scripts must be able to contain the 'GO' keyword which is not recognized by the standard `SqlClient`.

Comment: You could always parse your input with the "GO" statements and use that as an indicator to now execute your SQL statement, before proceeding with more lines of SQL... that way, you could use the standard SqlClient classes...

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that, though this is a super critical piece of code and I'd rather leave it as simple as possible.

Comment: I'd have to be very sure the parser handled text strings properly. I'm sure we will have stuff with something like update help set value = " ... GO .." where ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS worker processes are running as some user. When you use windows authentication, you are implicitly doing impersonation to the that user.

If your SQL server is on a different host, this probably isn't good enough. The impersonated user I think can only access local resources.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx#paght000025_usingimpersonation

Is SQL Server using windows authentication?

Comment: Not presently, though ideally we'd like to support bot SQL Server & Windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks for that, still doesn't explain the difference between SMO and a normal SqlClient or let me know what I should try next though?